# css "hover" not working on a slider

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, orbit

I am experiencing an issue using the hover inside the orbit slider, it doesn't work at all.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code and the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bonomi/KgndE/

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12">
        <ul data-orbit>
            <li>
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/Saturn-day-earth-smiled-1000x600.png" alt="slide 1"/>
                <div class="orbit-caption">
                Caption 1
                </div>
            </li>            
        </ul>
        <div class="orbit-caption">
        Caption 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.orbit-caption:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your selector isn't specific enough. Try:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7N4H2/)

```
.row .large-12 .orbit-caption:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

I'd suggest looking into [CSS specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) (mdn).

You were using a selector with a specificity value of `20` whereas the selector you were trying to overwrite: `.orbit-container .orbit-slides-container>* .orbit-caption` had a specificity of ~ `30`.

The selector `.row .large-12 .orbit-caption:hover` has a speciity of `40` <sub>(note the pseudo class)</sub>

Comment: Great answer! How do you measure the specifity?

Comment: @Bonomi Either do it manually (take a look at [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)). Or use a calculator like [this one](http://specificity.keegan.st/)